# Spring Mongo query not ignoring case

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I've the following query that is not ignoring case. What could be done to make this be case insensitive?

```
@Query("{'occasionId':?0,'text':/.*?1.*/}")
Page<FreeMessageCard> findByOccasionIdAndTextIgnoreCase(String occasionId, String text, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Is it not possible to specify it (the `i` option) in the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [@Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html) annotation, `spring-data` will not generate another query based on the naming convention for method names. If you want it to generate a query for you - don't use `@Query` annotation. Besides that, you can make your query work by doing this:

```
@Query("{'occasionId':?0,'text':/.*?1.*/i}")
Page<FreeMessageCard> findByOccasionIdAndTextIgnoreCase(String occasionId, String text, Pageable pageable);
```